# Using int value from properties Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I haven't seen such question anywhere, so I'm going to ask here about it. I have to make few instances of one object type, the number of how many instances I must instance should be provided from the file .properties. I tried using annotations @Value but it's always giving me

> NullPointerException

since the value is null.
So for example I have

> application.properties

in my resources folder.
Let's say the file look like this:

> instances.number=5
> ...

I use annotation:

```
@Value("${instances.number}")
private static String lastIndex;
```

And I want to use it in such way:

```
psvm {
for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(lastIndex); i++) {
//creating an instance of object
 }
}
```

So I cannot parse it since it's null value. What should I do to get instances.number value properly?

...

Comment: Just like `@Autowired`, injecting values with `@Value` only works in Spring beans. If your class is not a Spring bean, then these annotations do nothing and your field will remain `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because Spring doesn't support @Value on `static` fields.

Maybe try something like:

```java
@Component
public class PropertyClass {

    @Value("${lastIndex}")
    private integer lastIndex;

    private static Integer LAST_INDEX;

    @Value("${lastIndex}")
    public void setLastIndex(Integer lastIndex){
        PropertyClass.LAST_INDEX = lastIndex;
    }
}
```

Resource: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-static-field

Comment: I tried to use it in non-static way and it's still null.

Comment: @TadeuszM, make sure that the class where you are trying to inject the value from the properties file is a Spring Bean.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete static and try it

```
@Value("${instances.number}")
private String lastIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get value by @Value you should annotated class atleast @Component then it will assign value at runtime.

```
@Service
Public class Config{
@Autowried
 Environment env:

@Value("${instances.number}")
private String lastIndex;

public void test(){
 
System.out.println(env.getProperty("key"));
System.out.println(lastIndex)
}
```

If you would like to avoid such above problem you can use

```
environment.getProperty("keyName")
```

Comment: I still have null in both situations.